# Where can I find the 'Terminator Truck Chase' game mode?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLUZsTdySDA&list=PL3XZNMGhpynOuAanuf80lmuwj5QzPmc54&index=7). Alternatively, how can you make a similar game mode (one team needs to get to x, other team tries to kill them)?

Answer (score 1):

It's just one of the many gamemodes in GTA V. I'm not sure where they are located on the map, but you can easily access them with your phone. It's called "Hasta La Vista", which actually is mentioned in the description of the video.